# Python open file, parse into arrary, then search for sub-string in larger string. User Input not found, but hardcoded string is found

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, file, search, filter

I have two objectives:

1. Open an external file with data in it, then parse each line into an array with \n as the delimiter for each record.
2. Second objective is to search for a sub-string in the array of larger strings. For my test data I am using weather data and am using a date string to find the entire record in that array that holds attributes like high temp, date, low temp, etc. I need to return the entire record that holds the substring defined by the user input.

The problem I am having is my input is not found with this method. For example, user inputs `19490101` (which is a date time group), which should return the first record:

```
GHCND:USW00013741 SPOKANE REGIONAL AIRPORT WA US 366.1 37.31667 -79.96667 19490101 0.00 44 27
```

But instead returns nothing.

**BUT when I make that same value a hard coded string in the python function it works (e.g. `begin = '19490101'`)**

What am I missing?

```
    def openFile():
        begin = print(input("What date would you like to start your weather data query with?    Please enter the date in this format YYYYMMDD  "))

        lines = tuple(open('/Users/jasontt/data.txt', 'r'))
        print(lines)
        print("")
        print("")
        begin= str(begin).strip()

        res = [i for i in lines if begin in i]
        print(res)
```

Here is some sample data:

```
STATION           STATION_NAME                                       ELEVATION  LATITUDE   LONGITUDE  DATE     PRCP     TMAX     TMIN
----------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- -------- -------- --------
GHCND:USW00013741                     SPOKANE REGIONAL AIRPORT WA US      366.1   37.31667  -79.96667 19490101 0.00     44       27
GHCND:USW00013741                     SPOKANE REGIONAL AIRPORT WA US      366.1   37.31667  -79.96667 19490102 0.00     42       25
GHCND:USW00013741                     SPOKANE REGIONAL AIRPORT WA US      366.1   37.31667  -79.96667 19490103 0.15     46       30
GHCND:USW00013741                     SPOKANE REGIONAL AIRPORT WA US      366.1   37.31667  -79.96667 19490104 0.03     41       30
```

Comment: Change `begin = print(input("..."))` to `begin = input("...")`  `print()` function returns always `None`

Comment: Thanks, Andrej! I had a feeling it was going to be something that simple.